# Can someone please help me with a for loop java code

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, bluej

Could anyone please help me identify what's wrong with my code to this instruction here: http://prntscr.com/1w02ns
I'm not sure what's quite wrong. Most of the tests in my blueJ project are passing but, some arent.

My code so far here:

```
 String prefix (String n, int num)
    {
        int count = 0 ;
        for(int i = 0; i <n.length(); i++)
        {
            if(n.charAt(i) == num)
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
```

Comment: This is not the best place to as somebody to do your homework. :)

Comment: The provided code is super bug free. Error is some where else.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?..Stack trace??Looks like you have asked a question in similar context.You wont be getting proper replies,unless you have modified your question,so that we can understand.

Comment: What is the purpose of this?! Did you even think of mentioning that to us, based on which we may try to validate it(though, nobody would do that either)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case variable `count` is not used.

If you really want to use a loop, not a substring, you can try something like:

```
String prefix(String str, int n) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result += str.toCharArray()[i];
        }
        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using a loop? Your assignment just states that you need to accept a String and a number.

You can just do:

```
public String prefix(String text, int characters) {
 return text.substring(0, characters);
}
```

Reference: [toString javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Edit:
Why is it failing, and how is it determined? Are there any requirements/rules that we may need to know?
The following JUnit test works fine:

```
@Test
public void testPrefix() {
    Assert.assertEquals("hel", prefix("hello", 3));
}
```

Comment: A void method with a return String statement. Awesome!

Comment: @R.J you might want to learn how the edit function works on Stack overflow. I just wrote the function in half a second so mistakes do happen sometimes. But anyways, I fixed my answer.

Comment: If there was a typo or something, I would have loved to fix it. Plus, why would you be in such a hurry that you'd go ahead and post an answer with so many bugs?!

Comment: Nah. That's not working either :/ @SimonVerhoeven

Comment: @R.J. because it's a simple question and I just wanted to give him a quick pointer. BlueJavaMan What is the error?

Comment: @R.J There's no specific errors. Our tutors have just set tests so our code can go through them. If they pass all the tests, then our code is working fine. Else, it's not. Just to tests different 'private' num variable to determine what it returns. In this example it's 3. Well, in the tests they have different numbers to 3...

Comment: @blueJavaMAN the amount of characters is a variable in my function so it should work fine. Or is there a specific desired behaviour when the number is negative? Could you show the failing test?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use the substring function provided in java-string API.There are two version of this substring you can use the 2nd one.
below is the link

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm

Answer (score 0):

Why loop man?
use substring na??

```
public class Prefix {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String r = prefix("Why loop? use substring. Well unless your homework says use loop" , 4);
        System.out.println(r);
    }

    private static String prefix(String string, int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return string.substring(0,i);

    }

}
```

Comment: Nah, yeah. I either have to use a FOR loop or a WHILE loop :/ @harsha

Comment: It's alright now. Thanks everyone! Got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use :

```
static String prefix(String n, int num) throws Exception {
    if (n != null && n.length() < num)
        throw new Exception();

    return n.substring(0, num);

}
```

Comment: It's alright now. Thanks everyone! Got it now :)

Comment: @blueJavaMAN would you mind marking one as the answer?